# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in PHP 7.3

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site running on PHP 7.3 and since updating I am receiving the following error on the front end of the website:

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /homepages/36/d362586048/htdocs/genag/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3378

The code on that line is

```
$words_array = preg_split( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $num_words + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
```

Can anyone help with what I should be changing the line to for correcting the error?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `$num_words` is not numeric ? Also you can double check the line before the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php), it is happening when the addition operator is being used on `$num_words`.

You could cast `$num_words` to an integer to avoid this warning.

`$words_array = preg_split( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, (int)$num_words + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );`

I would suggest identifying why `$num_words` isn't an integer first though.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. This is an old theme so I'm sure a lot of the code is not up to current standards.

Comment: @user3612498 Glad that worked. I don't know much about wordpress, but if there is a setting to suppress/disable PHP warning outputs you could enable it to prevent these warnings from being displayed to your users. These warnings won't stop the script from running, they are more used for debugging and enforcing better programming practices.